# Suppress warning from ps -aux on Linux

Tags: linux, ps

When I run the `ps` command i get a warning saying `Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ`.

How do i suppress this warning? Is there some system setting that i must do for this. The command that I fire is:

```
[root@localhost home]# ps -aux | grep "curl -s -o Test" 
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ
root      4856  0.0  0.0   4044   672 pts/0    S+   07:20   0:00 grep curl -s -o Test
[root@localhost home]#
```

Note that I have to fire the exact same command as above(I cannot change the `-aux` to `aux`, I cannot redirect `STDERR` output). That is why i am looking for some system setting that will suppress the warning.

Comment: `ps -ef` (POSIX/SysV) or `ps aux` (BSD). Choose your side.

Comment: This command is fired by a subroutine that i call from my script. I cannot change the subroutine. The subroutine further expects no such warning. Hence i cannot change the command.

Comment: It seems like the bug is in the script, it's calling `ps` incorrectly.

Comment: So the subroutine is written in such a way that generates a warning and also cannot handle that warning?  Why would you be required to use this subroutine when it sounds like it could never possibly succeed on your system?

Answer (score 2):

Linux's `ps` command can emulate `ps` implementations from various Unix flavors. Set the environment variable `PS_PERSONALITY` to `bsd` to make it silently accept `-aux` as meaning “list all processes using the traditional BSD column set”. From a shell script:

```
PS_PERSONALITY=bsd /command/you/cannot/modify
```

From C:

```
setenv("PS_PERSONALITY", "bsd", 1);
function_you_cannot_modify();
unsetenv("PS_PERSONALITY");
```

Answer (score 0):

The ugly answer is: write a script that takes arguments that look like `ps` arguments,
sanitizes them (at a minimum, replaces `-aux` with `aux`),
and then calls `/bin/ps` with the sanitized arguments. 
Call it `ps` and put it in your private `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You write the `ps` command is part of a subroutine - this solution works if it is a shell function you call, or a shell script you `source`; It does not work if you execute the shell script containing the `ps` command.

You can define a shell function with the name `ps`, that replaces the command in path, and calls the real command itself, with some modifications of the output, like redirecting the STDERR:

```
function ps() {
    command ps "$@" 2>/dev/null
}
```

An example using `ls`:

```
$ ls -d /etc /missing
ls: cannot access /missing: No such file or directory
/etc
$ function ls() {          
    command ls "$@" 2>/dev/null
}
$ ls -d /etc /missing
/etc
```