# "Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?" has started to appear when connecting to server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon

I am suddenly seeing the following warning when I ssh to my server. I researched it and cannot seem to find the cause neither I am able to get rid of it.

Please, can someone help?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151237/suppress-warning-from-ps-aux-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is produced by the `ps` command when you use a syntax such as `ps -aux`. See this QA for a discussion on how to suppress this warning: [Suppress warning from ps -aux on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151237/173368)

The reason for the warning message is straightforward. `ps` supports options of three types: POSIX style options with one dash (`-e`), BSD style options with no dash (`a`), and GNU-style options with two dashes (`--forest`). Mixing different types of options, specifically `-aux` and `aux` will produce this warning. This is described in the [project's FAQ:](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/wikis/faq)

> Why does "ps -aux" complain about a bogus '-'?
>
> According to the POSIX
> and UNIX standards, the above command asks to display all processes
> with a TTY (generally the commands users are running) plus all
> processes owned by a user named "x".  If that user doesn't exist, then
> ps will assume you really meant "ps aux".  The warning is given to
> gently break you of a habit that will cause you trouble if a user
> named "x" were created.

Since you're seeing this on login, the offending `ps` command is likely inside your login profile (~/.bash_profile for the `bash` shell).

Comment: Looking further into this, it seems it's the following line in the bash_profile that's causing it.

`eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)`

The problem is, if I delete or comment the line, I can no longer use the `brew` command. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: @PtiSinge I'm not familiar enough with brew, so I might be wrong here. But based on the manpage, `brew shellenv` should just print out a bunch of `export` statements. Coupled with `eval`, that's a way to add a set of variables to the shell environment (which are probably required by brew). I don't see how this can cause a problem with `ps`.

Comment: @PtiSinge The `.bash_profile` file was the most obvious place to contain the `ps` command, but there are a few other possibilities you can check. See this QA for details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117470/173368

Comment: The thing is, if I comment the line in the `.bash_profile` and source it. The warning disappears. Just I can't use the Homebrew `brew` command now. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to Homebrew, specifically [this line](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/c75aaed83189a3964a1c437b3dcfafd150ccbd59/Library/Homebrew/cmd/shellenv.sh#L19). Your `ps` use the `c` flag instead `-c`.

The `eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)` instruction evaluates which SHELL you are using to export the proper format regarding PATH variables:

When I got this error I define manually the `brew` variables in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=${HOMEBREW_PREFIX};
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR=${HOMEBREW_CELLAR};
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=${HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY}
export HOMEBREW_SHELLENV_PREFIX=${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}
export PATH=${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin:${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}
export MANPATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:"
export INFOPATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}"
```